# Double click necessity on "input[]:focus"

Tags: javascript, css, input, focus

Got an issue with focus on button, which have **"input"** type.

I have a button which is `<input type="submit">` (css - `input[type="submit"]` ).
This button has primary style and hover style.
Also i wish to add a style on focus (on click) with some sort of loading animation.

The problem is in need to click twice for submit: first - on button, second - on style, which shows on first click. Because of it, action doesn't starts, so loading animation shows infinitely.

I represent this trouble at CodePen, so you can check it by yourself.
*https://codepen.io/Auditive/pen/OeVdYL*.

On CodePen you need to click on "Submit" button, then would be loading animation, on which you need to click again to perform submit action.
On second try it doesn't repeats, but if reload code snippet or page - it happens again.

Also I duplicate code here:

```js
function ShowResult() {
  setTimeout(function() {
     var result = document.getElementById("result");
     if (result.style.display === "none") {
       result.style.display = "block";
     } else {
       result.style.display = "none";
     }
   }, 2000); //Delay for 2 seconds
}

function ShowMain() {
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  if (result.style.display === "block") {
    result.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    result.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');

body {
  background: #222;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#result {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333, #444);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  animation: fadein 0.25s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  background: #fff0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #fff0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  background: #fff0;
  color: #56ef56;
  border: 1px solid #56ef56;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #56ef56;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  animation: glow 1s linear infinite;
}

input[type="submit"]:focus {
  background: #262626;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/gVX3yPJ.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  color: #fff0;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #fff0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  outline: 0;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #45cb45;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: fading 2s linear infinite;
}

#btn-close {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #353535;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ff444400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #0000;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#btn-close:hover {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #353535;
  color: #ff4444;
  border: 1px solid #ff444400;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes glow {
  0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #56ef56;}
  50% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #56ef5600;}
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #56ef56;}
}

@keyframes fading {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  50% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
      <input type="submit" onclick="ShowResult()" value="Submit Me">
    <div id="result">
      <p>
        Submitted!
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/X3D85Ns.png">
      </p>
      <button id="btn-close" onclick="ShowMain()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Asking for any ideas about solution.
With hope.
Please.

P.S.: Image & GIF used only for test and taken from Google Pictures, i haven't any copyright claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this if-condition inside your **ShowResult()** function

```
if (result.style.display === "none") {
```

When this is called for the first time the display property is not **none** as you might expect - it is just an empty string. Later on you're explicity setting it to none that's why it works afterwards.

To fix, make the if-condition look for an empty string as well

```
if (result.style.display == "none" || result.style.display == "") {
```